# FastReport 6 Installing for Delphi 10.3 and 10.4

Tags: delphi, installation, fastreport

after installing new version FR6 prof (fr679allpro.exe) for Delphi 10.3 and 10.4 the Delphi Ver 10.4 works fine.

But wenn starting Delphi 10.3 i get an error that a DLL 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\fs26.bpl' was not found. After clicking 'ok' then next message is "Package C:\Programm Files (x86)\FastReport 6 VCL Professional\LibD26\dclfrx26.bpl is missing"

After next klick, i got the first message, then the second message with other DLL-Names, and so on.

Then i uninstall the FR6, delete all the rests of directories and i delete the "FastReport" structur in regiedit. Then new installation (ofcourse with admin-rights), but the same again. I also try recomplie all version (x86 and 64 Bit) but always the same error.

what can i do - especially my 10.4 is working fine!

sorry for my bad english! Thank you and best regards Rolf

Comment: Contact FastReport support via their website. They wrote the installer, and should provide support for using it as you're using the paid (Pro) version. We can help with problems related to using FastReports from code.

Comment: Hi Ken, i have had contact with FR, but all tips i have got, won't work.

Comment: the wroteWhen you installed the latest version did you:

_first uninstall the previous version?
delete all traces of FastReport and FastScript from the system folders?
install the latest version on a "clean" system?
run the Recompile.exe routine against all of your Platforms (10.3 and 10.4)?
Unfortunately with the current FR Installer you cannot "update in place"._

Comment: Those instructions tell you what you need to do. Saying they *won't work* isn't useful. They do work. We can't tell you anything more than what they've already said. If you need more details, contact them again for more help, providing an answer for the questions they've asked.

Comment: sorry for my bad english: i don't want to say FR isn't work - my installation on my pc dos not work!

Comment: I know. You said you're having trouble installing, and I said that FR support are the ones that can help. We did not write the installer, and we don't have any way to help here.

Comment: @KenWhite - It is easy to send the man to ask for support to the vendor; but not helpful (as he said, they are not able to help). Helpful would be to provide an actual solution. That's the purpose of SO, to provide valid solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install FastReport
2. Locate the BPLs (for example c:\Libraries\FastReports\LibD27\frx*.bpl )
3. Optionally, copy the BPLs manually to c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl\
4. Install BPLs manually via the IDE (see Install packages menu).
5. In the IDE add the path to the DCU files to your "Library" (and maybe Browsing) paths.